# <canvas> coordinate space vs. dimensions

Tags: html, canvas

Consider a 4x4 pixel HTML canvas element.

The coordinate system spans from (0,0) in the top left to (4,4) in the bottom right.

This represents a 5x5 grid.

It seems like the canvas squeezes one extra pixel in each dimension, without changing the width or height. How do I account for this if I want to draw precise pixels on an NxN canvas?

Comment: What? A 4x4 canvas represents a 4x4 grid. Coordinate 0 is half a pixel on the left of the center of the first cell (or at top left corner of the 1x1 rectangle this pixel represents) and coordinate 4 is half a pixel on the right of the center of last cell (or top-right corner of this pixel) [0-4] inclusive.

Comment: @Kaiido so, the coordinates refer to the corners of a pixel? ie. each corner of a pixel has a different (x,y)?

Comment: Well just like any grid-system yes. Pixel at 0,0 extends until pixel at 1,1, it is actually a 1x1 rect. The coordinates refer to the position on this grid system, they can be float too. But yes, with default matrix transform, integer coordinates fall on boundaries of pixels.

Comment: Perfect, that answers it.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates (x,y) don't *index* pixels as if the canvas is a 2-d array.

In this case the region between grid lines *does* coincide with single pixels, but if we treat the canvas as a pixmap, then a pixel is the space between gridlines.

To draw pixel (i, j) with top-left corner at (x,y), do

```
canvas_context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```